# Send Alamofire request with parameters in swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I want to send a request with some parameters in swift.
body has XML content also.
http://example.com/POST

```
Body is : xml = "<root>abc</root>"
user : "admin"
ID : "21User"
```

I found `Alamofire` code which has `responseJSON`, but my response will not be JSON.
It'll be XML. So how to use it ?

Answer (score 0):

The Alamofire request could look like this:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://something.com", parameters: Dictionary() , encoding: .Custom({
            (convertible, params) in
            let mutableRequest = convertible.URLRequest.copy() as! NSMutableURLRequest

            let data = (self.testString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            mutableRequest.HTTPBody = data
            mutableRequest.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            return (mutableRequest, nil)
        }))
    .responseJSON { response in
    print(response.response) 
    print(response.result)   
    }
}
```

Try same, but use responseData or responseString instead of responseJSON .

Comment: Iam sorry to mention that it is a  POST request

Comment: Iam getting an error, extra argument in call.. How did you use define params?